# How to filter subqueries in Linq and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I filter the subqueries? When selecting `Payment` entities, I want to select `where Active == true`.

Expression:

```
public async Task<Invoice> InvoiceAsync(Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> predicate) => await ExecSingleAsync(this.GetDbSet<Invoice>()
    .Include(inv => inv.Actions)
    .Include(inv => inv.Account)
    .Include(inv => inv.Customer)
    .Include(inv => inv.Payments)
        .Where(pm => pm.Active)
    .Include(inv => inv.Lines)
        .Where(ln => ln.Active)
    .Where(inv => inv.Active)
    .Where(predicate));
```

Invoice.cs:

```
public class Invoice : DbAssets, IInvoice
{
    public int BillingClientId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceLine> Lines { get; set; } = new HashSet<InvoiceLine>();
    public DateTime BillingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceAction> Actions { get; set; } = new HashSet<InvoiceAction>();
    public string? Message { get; set; }
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<InvoicePayment> Payments { get; set; } = new HashSet<InvoicePayment>();

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal Total => this.Lines.Sum(ln => ln.Sum);

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal TotalPaid => this.Payments.Sum(pm => pm.Amount);

    [NotMapped]
    public InvoiceStatus Status => this.TotalPaid >= this.Total ? InvoiceStatus.Closed : InvoiceStatus.Open;

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal Mva => this.Lines.Sum(ln => ln.Mva);
}
```

Payment.cs:

```
public sealed class InvoicePayment : DbAssets, IInvoicePayment
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Both classes have an `Active` field.

Comment: Maybe you need [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) ?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes maybe. but shouldn't it be possible to define it in a query? It would be so much simpler

Comment: Or you can do that for collection navigation properties `.Include(inv => inv.Actions.Where(a => a.Active))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task<Invoice> InvoiceAsync(Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> predicate) => await ExecSingleAsync(this.GetDbSet<Invoice>()
    .Include(inv => inv.Actions)
    .Include(inv => inv.Account)
    .Include(inv => inv.Customer)
    .Include(inv => inv.Payments.Where(p => p.Active))
    .Include(inv => inv.Lines)
    .Where(inv => inv.Active)
    .Where(predicate));
```